# Incorrect activity restoring

Tags: android

I have a set of activities. Main activity with image background. Child activities with transparent background. Each child activity hides its views before starting a new one. I use view alpha = 0 and visibility View.INVISIBLE. I leave my app in one of child activities. After 8 or more hours I start app from launcher. All activities get restored by ActivityManager. But alpha and visibility properties of all views of all activities before current child get default values! I see views of all activities.

Expected that all views are stayed in previous state, i.e. invisible. All activities under current one don't receive events such as onCreate, onResume, onRestart, onRestoreInstanceState during app restoring.

Theme of child activities:

```
<style name="MyTranslucent" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

I need background in main activity as I animate it during activities transitions.

Comment: Why are you layering Activities with transparent backgrounds?

Comment: I animate background when activities transitions occurs. Shift it.